# calling other function from callback function

Tags: javascript, callback

I like to have some help... being stuck with this for a while.

```
var inventoryID = '123456';

function pickupFail(){
    db = window.openDatabase("myInvetory", "1.0", "myInvetory", 200000);
    db.transaction(queryUpdateInventory, dbError);
}

function queryUpdateInventory(tx){
    var sql = "SELECT inventoryCount FROM Inventory WHERE inventoryID = ?";
    tx.executeSql(sql, [inventoryID], finalizeUpdateInventory, dbError);
}

function finalizeUpdateInventory(tx, results){
   ....
   var inventoryCount = 0;
   var inventory = results.rows.item(0);
   ....
   inventoryCount = inventory.count;
   ....
   ....
   otherFunction(inventoryCount); // CALLING THIS PRODUCE CALLBACK ERROR
   ....
}

function otherFunction(count,...){
   ....
   //THIS IS LENGTHILY FUNCTION AND BEING USED BY OTHER FUNCTION AS WELL

}
```

Frankly said, I'm very novice on Cordova and javascript callback concept. I really do appreciate help from you guys.

Comment: What is the error message you're getting? If otherfunction takes more than 1 param, why are you only calling it with one?

Comment: To be exact, this is the error: 
Database Error:0 - the statement callback raised an exception or statement error callback did not return false

Comment: if I comment out call to otherFunction, no error occur.

Comment: after intensive, I finally found the error inside otherFunction. It seems that otherFunction is calling html element that not exist in that same page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the error inside otherFunction. It seems that otherFunction is calling html element that not exist in that same page. This html element exist in other pages that use otherFunction.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a function and defining it later. Defining `otherFunction(count)` before `finalizeUpdateInventory()` should remove the error. 
So the modified code becomes:

```
var inventoryID = '123456';

function pickupFail(){
    db = window.openDatabase("myInvetory", "1.0", "myInvetory", 200000);
    db.transaction(queryUpdateInventory, dbError);
}

function queryUpdateInventory(tx){
    var sql = "SELECT inventoryCount FROM Inventory WHERE inventoryID = ?";
    tx.executeSql(sql, [inventoryID], finalizeUpdateInventory, dbError);
}

function otherFunction(count,...){
   ....
   //THIS IS LENGTHILY FUNCTION AND BEING USED BY OTHER FUNCTION AS WELL

}

function finalizeUpdateInventory(tx, results){
   ....
   var inventoryCount = 0;
   var inventory = results.rows.item(0);
   ....
   inventoryCount = inventory.count;
   ....
   ....
   otherFunction(inventoryCount); // CALLING THIS PRODUCE CALLBACK ERROR
   ....
}
```

Comment: Hi Nikhil, I'm sorry to say that having re-order function does solve the problem. The problem cause by otherFunction calling non-existance html element.